# py2neo - neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(db_string) crashes python; no error-log

Tags: python, rest, installation, neo4j

the last couple of days I installed Python 2.7.3 and Neo4J community edition 1.8.M01. I managed to get the embedded python bindings to work, but as I need the py2neo REST bindings I've installed them like described at http://py2neo.org/. Moreover I can't download directly from git due to a "Permission denied (publickey)" error so I took the available py2neo-1.2.6.tar.gz version from the download section.

While the installation itself was not the problem, I can't get the example to work as on calling neo4j.GraphDatabaseService('http://localhost:7474/db/data') python crashes without any error message - Win7 64bit only pops up a message that the applicationn does not respond. Java, Python and Neo4J are all running on 64 bit basis and the server is accessible on http://localhost:7474. I even tried to force an output as described here: [Catching a python app before it exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535403/catching-a-python-app-before-it-exits) - but still no stacktrace or error-log.

I've installed everything from scratch or via the executables provided at www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ several times now but nothing managed to get this example to work.

I have installed both tornado 2.2.1 and pycurl 7.23.1. pycurl.version_info() reveals:     `(3, '7.23.1', 464641, 'Windows', 28, 'OpenSSL/0.9.8s', 0, '1.2.5', ('gopher', 'http', 'https', 'imap', 'imaps', 'pop3', 'pop3s', 'rtsp', 'smtp', 'smtps'), None, 0, None)` - moreover

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://stackoverflow.com')
c.perform()
```

returns the content of the startpage.

I've followed the stacktrace via print-messages into tornado.IOLoop.start() and there into _run_callback() where it actually executes callback() and crashes. Not shure if the callback-function defined inside of tornado.HTTPClient.fetch() should be called here - printing the callback results in `<tornado.stack_context._StackContextWrapper object at ...>`

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Roman

---

edit: corrected port as of a typo

---

edit2: after a longer debug-session which narrowed the point of failure a bit, Nigel provided me with a way to deal with my issues by exchanging

```
self._http = http or httpclient.HTTPClient(curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient)
```

with

```
self._http = http or httpclient.HTTPClient()
```

in line 55 of rest.py. This is a workaround but does not solve the problem in the back of tornado/pycurl. The windows management console declares pycurl.pyd as the reason for the crash and as some of the nodes (after a seldom functioning intialization of the GraphDatabaseService) get stored within Neo4J and the Debug-Output below isn't shown anymore, the crash must occur between the send request and the return to the main application. I currently believe that either the Selection poll, which I fall back on Windows, is the reason for the crash or maybe the curl-handle gets shared between different threads - which should not happen (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) - and is somehow the most comprehensible reason imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you're having issues with py2neo. I haven't carried out any testing under Windows since I only run Linux so I'm unsure whether there are any general incompatibilities there. I am also aware that error reporting is less than it should be which has been limited by the amount of time I've had to work on the project.

That said, I notice that you are running on port 4747 instead of the default 7474 - or this this a typo? Have you tried your short cURL test against the root database URI directly?

You seem to have covered all the bases looking at the layers involved so I'm unsure what else to look at here. I have considered adding an option to be able to switch between the curl_httpclient and the simple_httpclient - this may give an alternative to try. I will try to get something put up over the next few days.

Nige

Comment: Since you've been able to demonstrate that cURL works directly against Neo4j and that I can't possibly envisage the problem being at the Python level, it seems logical to begin to look at the fault being within either Tornado or py2neo itself.

I don't want to take up this thread with too much back-and-forth of debugging detail so please feel free to drop me an email (address on the site) and we can work through the problem and then post a resolution back here. In the meantime, I will try to get hold of a Windows machine to do some testing and see if I can recreate the issue.

Nige

Comment: The simple_httpclient has now been made the default in 1.2.8, removing the cURL issue with Windows. Therefore no need for manual editing.